# RoR - ActiveAdmin Impossible to create a new product with nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am new to rails and I'm trying to customize ActiveAdmin.
My app has 3 models: User (which has many products), Product (which has many prices) and Price. I am trying to customize ActiveAdmin with a nested form to be able to create/update a product directly with its prices.
Although the update works perfectly (updating product and even adding a new price), the create action doesn't work. I get "rollback" in the console but no specific error message.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
# app/admin/products.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :size
    end
    f.inputs "Prices" do
      f.has_many :prices do |price|
        price.input :value
        price.input :currency, :collection => ["dollars", "euros", "pounds"]
      end
    end
  f.actions
end
permit_params :name, :size, :user_id, prices_attributes: [:id, :currency, :value, :product_id, :_edit, :_update, :_new, :_create]
```

I have also put "accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices" in app/models/product.rb.

The logs form the console

```
Started POST "/admin/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-28 14:46:05 +0200
Processing by Admin::ProductsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"W9OJHqyFzXREfi4/DuBN1xnf0KIhAjJDfGsZjQqvGJ7BZOb11fVAz78djOf1k3XZdmpJxuPYinYi6Knu2agvnQ==", "product"=>{"name"=>"Shorts", "size"=>"XL", "prices_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"value"=>"40", "currency"=>"euros"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
AdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendering /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.2.1/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb
Rendered /Users/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.2.1/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (100.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 248ms (Views: 132.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Can you post the controller method where you save the product? If instead of save you call save! it will throw an error and show why the product is failing to save rather than just rolling back

Comment: OK, that was my mistake, I had not modified the default ActiveRecord controller. I copied my code from my products_controller and it works. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries happy it's fixed :)